# Estou com um erro de conversão ao rodar um codigo C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Ao Rodar o codigo ele diz o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu der ok a aplicação roda normalmente mas os dados inseridos no banco não aparecem no DataGridView. Qual seria o meu erro?

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using AcessoDados.Contracts;
    using AcessoDados.Entities;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;


    namespace AcessoDados.Repositories
    {
    public class FuncionarioRepository : MasterRepository, IFuncionarioRepository
    {
        private string selectAll;
        private string insert;
        private string update;
        private string delete;

        public FuncionarioRepository()
        {
            selectAll = "Select Nome, Telefone, Cpf, Endereco, Numero, Bairro, Cep, Cidade, Estado, Salario from Funcionario";
            insert = "insert into Funcionario values(@Nome,@Telefone,@Cpf,@Endereco,@Numero,@Bairro,@Cep,@Cidade,@Estado,@Salario)";
            update = "update Funcionario set Nome=@Nome,Telefone=@Telefone,Cpf=@Cpf,Endereco=@Endereco,Numero=@Numero,Bairro=@Bairro,Cep=@Cep,Cidade=@Cidade,Estado=@Estado,Salario@Salario where Id=@Id";
            delete = "delete from Funcionario where Id=@Id";
        }
        public int Add(Funcionario entity)
        {
            parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Nome", entity.Nome));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Telefone", entity.Telefone));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Cpf", entity.Cpf));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Endereco", entity.Endereco));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Numero", entity.Numero));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Bairro", entity.Bairro));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Cep", entity.Cep));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Cidade", entity.Cidade));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Estado", entity.Estado));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Salario", entity.Salario));
            return ExecuteNonQuery(insert);


        }

        public int Editar(Funcionario entity)
        {
            parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", entity.Id));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Nome", entity.Nome));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Telefone", entity.Telefone));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Cpf", entity.Cpf));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Endereco", entity.Endereco));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Numero", entity.Numero));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Bairro", entity.Bairro));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Cep", entity.Cep));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Cidade", entity.Cidade));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Estado", entity.Estado));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Salario", entity.Salario));
            return ExecuteNonQuery(update);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Funcionario> GetAll()
        {
            var tableResult = ExecuteReader(selectAll);
            var listFuncionario = new List<Funcionario>();
            foreach (DataRow item in tableResult.Rows)
            {
                listFuncionario.Add(new Funcionario { 
                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(item[0]),
                    Nome = item[1].ToString(),
                    Telefone = item[2].ToString(),
                    Cpf = item[3].ToString(),
                    Endereco = item[4].ToString(),
                    Numero = Convert.ToInt32(item[5]),
                    Bairro = item[6].ToString(),
                    Cep = item[7].ToString(),
                    Cidade = item[8].ToString(),
                    Estado = item[9].ToString(),
                    Salario = (float) Convert.ToDouble(item[0])
                });
            }
            return listFuncionario;
        }

        public int Remover(int Id)
        {
            parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", Id));
            return ExecuteNonQuery(delete);
        }
    }
}
```

O Stack meio que bugou a indentação!

Comment: Da uma lida em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485 ,refaça sua pergunta com o codigo ao inves de imagem.

Comment: Coloquei a imagem pq o codigo ta bem grande mas vou colocar so essa parte entao.

Comment: Você deve estar fazendo errado, só o que postou não tem como ajudar

Comment: Coloquei o codigo todo.

Answer (score 0):

Pela imagem apresentada, o erro está na conversão de uma string para um inteiro. Os únicos lugares onde é feita tal conversão são `Convert.ToInt32(item[0])` e `Convert.ToInt32(item[5])`.

Ao olhar o seu select é possível verificar que o primeiro item retornado é o nome e não o id, como vc espera no seu foreach, e por isso o 1o `ToInt32` retorna erro.

Adicione o id à sua query e verifique se as demais propriedades estão na ordem correta. Uma coisa que poderia ajudar, nesses casos, é trocar todas as propriedades para string, assim vc já conseguiria verificar que algum campo da base de dados nao estaria sendo preenchido na propriedade correta.

Comment: Na imagem mostra que ele fez `Numero = Convert.ToInt32(item[0])` onde deveria ser `Numero = Convert.ToInt32(item[5])` também.

Comment: Sim, como houve o erro logo na primeira propriedade, todas as demais também estão erradas, só não vão apresentar erro por serem strings.